# Rolify has_role? returning true after remove_role

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, rolify, pundit

I would like to do the following

```
User1 = User.find(1)
User2 = User.find(2)
```

Add a role to users

```
User1.add_role :teacher
User2.add_role :teacher

User1.has_role? :teacher
>> true

User2.has_role? :teacher
>> true
```

Delete a role from a specific user

```
User1.remove_role :teacher

User1.has_role? :teacher
>> false

User2.has_role? :teacher
>> true
```

I am having a problem because currently

```
User1.has_role? :teacher
```

is returning TRUE even after a remove. However when I do User1.roles it returns an empty array as expected and has_any_roles? returns false as expected. Why is it returning TRUE even after the role is removed?

Answer (score 1):

you need to reload the user before checking if it has a role again

```
    User1.remove_role :teacher
    User1.has_role? :teacher
    -> true
    User1.reload

    User1.has_role? :teacher
    -> false
```